# Laravel Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" while scheduling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

This should be straigh forward buti don't know why it is not working . I am creating a command in laravel to send birtday email reminders on a user's birtday .

Everything works fine and the schedule function is triggered but comes with an error

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".
```

This is my command

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;
class SendBirthdayReminderEmail extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'email:birthday';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Email users a birthday Reminder message';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

     $users = User::whereMonth('dob', '=', date('m'))->whereDay('dob', '=', date('d'))->get();   
    foreach($users as $user) {   
        Mail::queue('emails.birthday', ['user' => $user], function ($mail) use ($user) {
            $mail->to($user['email'])
                ->from('info@XXXXXX.com', 'Company')
                ->subject('Happy Birthday!');
        });

     }

    $this->info('Birthday messages sent successfully!');

    }
}
```

And this is my kernel.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
     Commands\SendBirthdayReminderEmail::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {


        $schedule->command('email:birthday')->dailyAt('13:00')->timezone('Africa/Dar_es_Salaam');
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated . Thanks :-)

Comment: Maybe the double arrow (`->->`) between command() and dailyAt()?

Comment: Nevermind sorry..

Comment: btw you can delete that `__construct()`, since it just calls the parent. Without it, the parent gets called anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution,

```
/opt/php70/bin/php /home/sitename/public_html/artisan schedule:run >/dev/null 2>&1
```

initially i had 1 after schedule:run method . As below

```
/opt/php70/bin/php /home/sitename/public_html/artisan schedule:run 1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code all looks good.
Have you tried simply as below

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

after reaching at your root folder path.